# Mounting Rails 3 Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I created a Rails 3 engine that is namespaced. Within my engine, I have views, but they are in the `app/views/engine_name` folder.

When I mounted this engine into my project, I added `gem 'engine_name', path: '../engine_name'` to my Gemfile.

Now, when I go to mysite.local.com:3000/engine_name/controller, I get an error that it can't find the view. It's looking in `"/Users/shamoon/Sites/engine_name/app/views"` instead of `"/Users/shamoon/Sites/engine_name/app/engine_name/views"`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In routes, I put

```
  mount EngineName::Engine => "/path_to_engine", :as => "engine_name"
```